# Adding bits in the same position (or rank or level) in an array of numbers

Tags: bit-manipulation, big-o

Looking for a better algorithmic approach to my problem. Any insights to this is greatly appreciated.

I have an array of numbers, say

```
short arr[] = [16, 24, 24, 29]; 
// the binary representation of this would be [10000, 11000, 11000, 11101]
```

I need to add the bit in position 0 of every number and bit in position 1 of every number and so on.. store it in an array, so my output array should look like this:

```
short addedBitPositions = [4, 3, 1, 0, 1]; 
// 4 1s in leftmost position, 3 1s in letmost-1 position ... etc.
```

The solution that I can think is this:

```
addedBitPosition[0] = (2 pow 4) & arr[0] + (2 pow 4) & arr[1] + 
                      (2 pow 4) & arr[2] + (2 pow 4) & arr[3];

addedBitPosition[1] = (2 pow 3) & arr[0] + (2 pow 3) & arr[1] + 
                      (2 pow 3) & arr[2] + (2 pow 3) & arr[3];

... so on
```

If the length of arr[] grows to M and the number of bits in each M[i] grows to N, then the time complexity of this solution is O(M*N).

Can I do better? Thanks!

Comment: Something like this has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7793997/555045

Answer (score 0):

You may try masking each number with masks `0b100...100...100...1` with 1's in each `k` positions.  Then add the masked numbers together — you will receive sums of bits in positions 0, k, 2k...  Repeat this with mask shifted left by 1, 2, ..., (`k-1`) to receive the sums for other bits.  Of course, some more bithackery is needed to extract the sums.  Also, `k` must be chosen such that `2 ** k < M` (the length of the array), to avoid overflow.

I'm not sure it is really worth it, but might be for very long arrays and `N > log₂ M`.

**EDIT**

Actually, `N > log₂ M` is not a strict requirement.  You may do this for "small enough" chunks of the whole array, then add together extracted values (this is O(M)).  In bit-hacking the actual big-O is often overshadowed by the constant factor, so you'd need to experiment to pick the best `k` and the size of array chunk (assuming this technique gives any improvement over the straightforward summation you described, of course).