# Compute sum of bits efficiently with SSE

Tags: pointers, sse, simd

I have done a calculation using SSE to improve the performance of my code, of which  I include a [minimal working example](https://ufile.io/6xzo7). I have included comments and the compilation line to make it as clear as possible, please ask if you need any clarification.

I am trying to sum N bits, `bit[0], ..., bit[N-1]`, and write the result in binary in a vector `result[0], ..., result[bits_N-1]`, where `bits_N` is the number of bits needed to write N in binary. This sum is performed bit-by-bit: each `bit[i]` is an unsigned long long int, and into its j-th bit is stored either 0 or 1. As a result, I make 64 sums, each of N bit, in parallel.

In lines 80-105 I make this sum by using 64-bit arithmetic.

In lines 107-134 I do it by using SSE: I store the first half of the sum `bit[0], ...., bit[N/2-1]` in the first 64 bits of _m128i objects `BIT[0], ..., BIT[N/2-1]`, respectively. Similarly, I store `bit[N/2], ...., bit[N-1]` in the last 64 bits of `BIT[0], ..., BIT[N/2-1]`, respectively, and sum all the `BIT`s. So far everything works fine, and the 128-bit sum takes the same time as the 64-bit one. However, to collect the final result I need to sum the two halves to each other, see lines 125-132. This takes a long time, and makes me lose the gain obtained with SSE.

I am running this on an Intel(R) i7-4980HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz with gcc 7.2.0.

Do you know a way around this?

Comment: The real issue is how much SSE calculation you are doing before you need to 'spill to integers'. If you aren't doing enough work, then the moving of data back to integer space is likely going to do just what you describe in terms of overall performance. Remember also that ``_mm_extract_epi64`` is an SSE4 instruction, so it's not necessarily going to be supported on as many target machines. See [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/09/11/directxmath-sse4-1-and-sse4-2/)

Comment: @ Paul R I included a minimal working example of the code.

Comment: Since you're counting bits (I think?) you might like [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.07612.pdf)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting 1 bits (population count) on large data using AVX-512 or AVX-2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50085197).  Or my answer on [Fastest way to do horizontal float vector sum on x86](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35270026) shows how to do integer horizontal sums; in your case you'd want a shuffle + paddq.

Comment: @ Peter Cordes, the examples that you refer to are horizontal sums, while mine is a vertical sum, where 64 sums are made in parallel, see my explanayion. For the same reason, shuffle + padq will not work in my case.

Answer (score 1):

The low part can be trivially saved with `movq` instruction or either `_mm_storel_epi64 (__m128i* mem_addr, __m128i a);` intrinsic storing to memory, or `_mm_cvtsi128_si64` storing to register.

There is also a `_mm_storeh_pd` counterpart, which requires cast to `pd` and may cause a stall due to mixing floating points and integers.

The top part can be of course moved to low part with `_mm_shuffle_epi(src, 0x4e)` and then saved with `movq`.