# Population count in AVX512

Tags: simd, intrinsics, avx512, hammingweight

I have been trying to use _mm256_popcnt_epi64 on a machine that supports AVX512 and on code that has previously been optimiized for AVX2.

Unfortunately, I ran into the issue that the function isn't found.  The corresponding `__m512i` equivalent is found, however.  Is the `__m256i` function deprecated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`_mm512_popcnt_epi64`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=popcntq&expand=4365) is part of [AVX512-VPOPCNTDQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512#VPOPCNTDQ_and_BITALG).  The 256 and 128-bit versions also require AVX512VL to use AVX512 instructions with 128 or 256-bit vectors.

Mainstream AVX512 CPUs all have AVX512-VL.  Xeon Phi CPUs don't have AVX512-VL.

(`_mm512_popcnt_epi8` and epi16 are also new in Ice Lake, as part of [AVX512-BITALG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512#VPOPCNTDQ_and_BITALG))

Perhaps you forgot to enable the compiler options necessary (like GCC `-march=native` to enable everything the machine you're compiling on can do), or you're compiling for a target that doesn't have both features.  If so, then the compiler won't have a definition for `_m256_popcnt_epi64` as an intrinsic, so in C it will assume its and undeclared function and emit a call to it.  (Which will of course be not found at link time.)  And/or it will warn or error (C or C++) about a prototype not being found.

**Very few CPUs currently have AVX512-VPOPCNTDQ** ([wikipedia AVX512 feature vs. CPU matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512#CPUs_with_AVX-512)):

- Knight's Mill (final-generation Xeon Phi): only AVX512-VPOPCNTDQ, no AVX512VL and no BITALG.  So only the `__m512i` versions are available for `gcc -O3 -march=knm`.  You should definitely be using 512-bit vectors on Xeon Phi unless data layout works perfectly for 256 and would take extra shuffling for 512-bit.  But beware that it's slow for some AVX / AVX2 instructions that it doesn't have 512-bit versions of, like shuffles with elements smaller than 32-bit.  (No AVX512 BW)
- Ice Lake / Tiger Lake: has AVX512 VPOPCNTDQ, BITALG, and AVX512 VL, so `_mm256_popcnt_epi64` and `epi8` are supported when compiling for this target microarchitecture, e.g. `gcc -O3 -march=icelake-client`.  (Assuming your compiler's  headers are correct).

  **GCC8.3 and earlier have a bug where `-march=icelake-client` / `icelake-server` doesn't enable `-mavx512vpopcntdq`**.  (GCC7 doesn't know about `-march=icelake-client`). It's fixed in GCC8.4, so either upgrade to the latest GCC8, or better upgrade to the latest stable GCC; a couple more years of development should usually help GCC make better code with new ISA extensions like AVX-512, especially with mask registers.  Or just **manually use `-march=icelake-client -mavx512vpopcntdq`**; that does work: https://godbolt.org/z/a7bhcjdhr

---

Choosing between 256 vs. 512-bit vectors on Ice Lake is a tradeoff like on Skylake-x: when 512-bit vector uops are in flight, the vector ALUs on port 1 don't get used.  And max turbo clock speed may be lowered.  [SIMD instructions lowering CPU frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56852812/simd-instructions-lowering-cpu-frequency).  So if you don't get much speedup from wider vectors (e.g. because of a memory bottleneck, or your SIMD loops are only a tiny part of a larger program), it can hurt overall performance to use 512-bit vectors in one loop.

But note that Icelake Client CPUs aren't affected *much*, and I'm not sure if `vpopcnt` instructions even count as "heavy", maybe not reducing max turbo as much, if at all on client CPUs.  Most integer SIMD instructions don't count.  See discussion on [LLVM [X86] Prefer 512-bit vectors on Ice/Rocket/TigerLake (PR48336)](https://reviews.llvm.org/D111029).  The vector ALU part of port 1 still shuts down while 512-bit uops are in flight, though.

---

Other CPUs don't have hardware SIMD popcnt support at all, and no form of `_mm512_popcnt_epi64` is available.

Even if you only have AVX2, not AVX512 at all, SIMD popcnt is a win vs. scalar `popcnt`, over non-tiny arrays on modern CPUs with fast `vpshufb` (`_mm256_shuffle_epi8`).  **https://github.com/WojciechMula/sse-popcount/** has AVX2, and AVX512 versions that use `vpternlogd` for Harley-Seal accumulation to reduce the amount of SIMD LUT lookups for popcounting.

Also on Stack Overflow [Counting 1 bits (population count) on large data using AVX-512 or AVX-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50081465/counting-1-bits-population-count-on-large-data-using-avx-512-or-avx-2) shows some code copied from that repo a couple years ago.

If you need counts for separate elements separately, just use the standard unpack for `vpshufb` and `vpsadbw` against a zero vector to hsum into 64-bit qword chunks.

If you need *positional popcount* (separate sum for each bit-position), see https://github.com/mklarqvist/positional-popcount.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! I was working on Skylake and the intrinsics guide made me think that AVX512VL is enough.

Comment: @Alex: That doesn't explain `_mm512_popcnt_epi64` working for you.  It should also compiler error, or fault as an illegal instruction if you use compiler options that let it compile.  So check your build options.

Comment: My code is part of a larger project and I got casting errors when compiling when I tried to popcnt on `__m256i'. That's what made me think that this function is available. I will try to check it explicitly.

Comment: @Alex: That made you think the `__m512i` version was available?  Ok.  No it isn't available with `-march=skylake-avx512`.  I was just worried something else was totally wrong with your build options or test setup, but making wrong assumptions explains it just fine.

Comment: @PeterCordes : I am getting error on ice-lake `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/include/avx512vpopcntdqvlintrin.h:117:1: error: inlining failed in call to always_inline ‘__m256i _mm256_popcnt_epi64(__m256i)’: target specific option mismatch` . checked avx512 and other variants are present and also compiler flags -O3 -march=native is on. any idea what am i missing , any headers ?

Comment: @user179156: Are you maybe running in a VM that doesn't pass through AVX-512 in general, or some of the sub-features?  Since you say you have avx512, that rules out an an Ice-lake Pentium or Celeron that only have AVX2.  `-march=icelake-client` and `-march=icelake-server` both support it, but if your VM doesn't pass through AVX-512F then a binary built that way won't run.  (If a VM does pass through AVX-512F but fails to pass through some other AVX-512F feature bits, `-march=native` won't see it; it believes CPUID, but the instructions will actually run without faulting.)

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/74sx9TY3G : here it doesnt compile when i use `-march=native` but not when i use `-march=icelake-client` or `-march=icelake-server`

Comment: it seems like its a gcc version issue ,doesnt work with gcc 8 but compiles with 9 and later

Comment: @user179156: Not surprising for Godbolt; according to `-fverbose-asm` output (https://godbolt.org/z/aaEoorYs7), `-march=native` there is `-march=skylake-avx512`; it runs on AWS instances with SKX or Cascade Lake CPUs.  For now anyway; that's why it warns that `-march=native` depends on whatever AWS instance it runs on.

Comment: @user179156: As for `-march=icelake-client`, yeah interesting, seems GCC8.3 and earlier have a bug where they think ICL doesn't have `-mavx512vpopcntdq`  (But they do enable `-mavx512bitalg`, so amusingly it does support `_mm256_popcnt_epi8` and epi16).  https://godbolt.org/z/YMqGGs67G.  If `-march=native` detection of extensions from CPUID is also affected by that bug, that would break things even for local usage.  (GCC7 and earlier don't know about `-march=icelake-client` at all.)

Comment: @user179156: Thanks for bringing that bug in older GCC to my attention; updated my answer in case future readers have the same problem.  Turns out `-march=icelake-client -mavx512vpopcntdq` does work with GCC8.3