# Bloated code generated for __builtin_popcnt when -mavx2 is on

Tags: c, assembly, x86, clang, compiler-optimization

For such a function, `clang` (and sometimes `gcc` in certain contexts that I cannot reproduce minimally) seems to generate bloated code when `-mavx2` switch is on.

```
unsigned count(uint64_t *f) {
    unsigned c = 0;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 1024; ++i) {
        if (sizeof(long) >= 8) {
            c += __builtin_popcountl(f[i]);
        } else {
            c += __builtin_popcountll(f[i]);
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

This is from `gcc` and it's quite straightforward.

```
count:
        lea     rcx, [rdi+8192]
        xor     eax, eax
.L2:
        xor     edx, edx
        add     rdi, 8
        popcnt  rdx, QWORD PTR [rdi-8]
        add     eax, edx
        cmp     rcx, rdi
        jne     .L2
        ret
```

However `clang` decides to generate this massive bloat when `-mavx2` is on. `-mpopcnt` was also set.

```
.LCPI0_0:
        .zero   32,15
.LCPI0_1:
        .byte   0                               # 0x0
        .byte   1                               # 0x1
        .byte   1                               # 0x1
        .byte   2                               # 0x2
        .byte   1                               # 0x1
        .byte   2                               # 0x2
        .byte   2                               # 0x2
        .byte   3                               # 0x3
        .byte   1                               # 0x1
        .byte   2                               # 0x2
        .byte   2                               # 0x2
        .byte   3                               # 0x3
        .byte   2                               # 0x2
        .byte   3                               # 0x3
        .byte   3                               # 0x3
        .byte   4                               # 0x4
        .byte   0                               # 0x0
        .byte   1                               # 0x1
        .byte   1                               # 0x1
        .byte   2                               # 0x2
        .byte   1                               # 0x1
        .byte   2                               # 0x2
        .byte   2                               # 0x2
        .byte   3                               # 0x3
        .byte   1                               # 0x1
        .byte   2                               # 0x2
        .byte   2                               # 0x2
        .byte   3                               # 0x3
        .byte   2                               # 0x2
        .byte   3                               # 0x3
        .byte   3                               # 0x3
        .byte   4                               # 0x4
count:                                  # @count
        vpxor   xmm0, xmm0, xmm0
        xor     eax, eax
        vmovdqa ymm1, ymmword ptr [rip + .LCPI0_0] # ymm1 = [15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15]
        vmovdqa ymm2, ymmword ptr [rip + .LCPI0_1] # ymm2 = [0,1,1,2,1,2,2,3,1,2,2,3,2,3,3,4,0,1,1,2,1,2,2,3,1,2,2,3,2,3,3,4]
        vpxor   xmm12, xmm12, xmm12
        vpxor   xmm4, xmm4, xmm4
        vpxor   xmm5, xmm5, xmm5
        vpxor   xmm6, xmm6, xmm6
.LBB0_1:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        vmovdqu ymm7, ymmword ptr [rdi + 8*rax]
        vmovdqu ymm8, ymmword ptr [rdi + 8*rax + 32]
        vmovdqu ymm9, ymmword ptr [rdi + 8*rax + 64]
        vmovdqu ymm10, ymmword ptr [rdi + 8*rax + 96]
        vpand   ymm11, ymm7, ymm1
        vpshufb ymm11, ymm2, ymm11
        vpsrlw  ymm7, ymm7, 4
        vpand   ymm7, ymm7, ymm1
        vpshufb ymm7, ymm2, ymm7
        vpaddb  ymm7, ymm11, ymm7
        vpsadbw ymm7, ymm12, ymm7
        vpand   ymm11, ymm8, ymm1
        vpshufb ymm11, ymm2, ymm11
        vpsrlw  ymm8, ymm8, 4
        vpand   ymm8, ymm8, ymm1
        vpshufb ymm8, ymm2, ymm8
        vpaddb  ymm8, ymm8, ymm11
        vpsadbw ymm8, ymm8, ymm12
        vpand   ymm11, ymm9, ymm1
        vpshufb ymm11, ymm2, ymm11
        vpsrlw  ymm9, ymm9, 4
        vpand   ymm9, ymm9, ymm1
        vpshufb ymm9, ymm2, ymm9
        vpaddb  ymm9, ymm9, ymm11
        vpsadbw ymm9, ymm9, ymm12
        vpand   ymm11, ymm10, ymm1
        vpshufb ymm11, ymm2, ymm11
        vpsrlw  ymm10, ymm10, 4
        vpand   ymm10, ymm10, ymm1
        vpshufb ymm10, ymm2, ymm10
        vpaddb  ymm10, ymm10, ymm11
        vpsadbw ymm10, ymm10, ymm12
        vextracti128    xmm3, ymm7, 1
        vpackusdw       xmm3, xmm7, xmm3
        vpaddd  xmm0, xmm0, xmm3
        vextracti128    xmm3, ymm8, 1
        vpackusdw       xmm3, xmm8, xmm3
        vpaddd  xmm4, xmm4, xmm3
        vextracti128    xmm3, ymm9, 1
        vpackusdw       xmm3, xmm9, xmm3
        vpaddd  xmm5, xmm5, xmm3
        vextracti128    xmm3, ymm10, 1
        vpackusdw       xmm3, xmm10, xmm3
        vpaddd  xmm6, xmm6, xmm3
        add     rax, 16
        cmp     rax, 1024
        jne     .LBB0_1
        vpaddd  xmm0, xmm4, xmm0
        vpaddd  xmm0, xmm5, xmm0
        vpaddd  xmm0, xmm6, xmm0
        vpshufd xmm1, xmm0, 238                 # xmm1 = xmm0[2,3,2,3]
        vpaddd  xmm0, xmm0, xmm1
        vpshufd xmm1, xmm0, 85                  # xmm1 = xmm0[1,1,1,1]
        vpaddd  xmm0, xmm0, xmm1
        vmovd   eax, xmm0
        vzeroupper
        ret
```

`clang`'s code is similar to `gcc` when only `-mpopcnt` is on, with a bit of unrolling.

```
count:                                  # @count
        xor     ecx, ecx
        xor     eax, eax
.LBB0_1:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        popcnt  rdx, qword ptr [rdi + 8*rcx]
        add     edx, eax
        popcnt  rsi, qword ptr [rdi + 8*rcx + 8]
        add     esi, edx
        popcnt  rdx, qword ptr [rdi + 8*rcx + 16]
        popcnt  rax, qword ptr [rdi + 8*rcx + 24]
        add     edx, esi
        add     eax, edx
        add     rcx, 4
        cmp     rcx, 1024
        jne     .LBB0_1
        ret
```

According to this document (https://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf), `popcnt` is a very cheap instruction on most architectures. Then why is `clang` generating such a bloat to replace `popcnt` when I clearly allowed to use it with `-mpopcnt`? The optimization level was all set to `-O3`.

Here is a link to godbolt (https://godbolt.org/z/4vWK33a7c).

Comment: If you want to compute the population of large arrays, consider implementing an algorithm like [Muła's](https://github.com/WojciechMula/sse-popcount).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It's auto-vectorizing as well as unrolling, which is a performance win for large arrays (or would be if clang had less overhead)**, at least on Intel CPUs where `popcnt` is 1/clock, so 64 bits per clock.  (AMD Zen has 3 or 4/clock `popcnt`, so with `add` instructions taking an equal amount of the 4 scalar-integer ALU ports, it could sustain 2/clock uint64_t popcnt+load and add.)  https://uops.info/

But `vpshufb` is also 1/clock on Intel (or 2/clock on Ice Lake), and if it's the bottleneck that's 128 bits of popcount work per clock.  (Doing table lookups for the low 4 bits of each of 32 bytes.)  But it's certainly not going to be that good, with all the extra shuffling it's doing inside the loop. :/

This vectorization loses on Zen1 where the SIMD ALUs are only 256 bits wide, but should be a significant win on Intel, and maybe a win on Zen2 and later.

---

But looks like clang widens to 32-bit counts inside the inner loop with `vpsadbw`, so it's not as good as it could be.  1024x `uint64_t` is 256 `__m256i` vectors of input data, and clang is unrolling by 4 so the max count in any one element is only 64, which can't overflow.

Clang is unrolling a surprising amount, given how much work it does.  The `vextracti128` and `vpackusdw` don't make much sense to me, IDK why it would do that inside the loop.  The simple way to vectorize without overflow risk is just `vpsadbw` -> `vpaddq` or `vpaddd`, and it's already using `vpsadbw` for horizontal byte sums within 8-byte chunks.  (A better way is to defer that until just before the byte elements could overflow, so do a few `vpaddb`.  Like in [How to count character occurrences using SIMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54541129/how-to-count-character-occurrences-using-simd), although the byte counters are only incremented by 0 or 1 there, rather than 0 .. 8)

See [Counting 1 bits (population count) on large data using AVX-512 or AVX-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50081465/counting-1-bits-population-count-on-large-data-using-avx-512-or-avx-2), especially Wojciech Muła's big-array popcnt functions: https://github.com/WojciechMula/sse-popcount/ - clang is using the same strategy as `popcnt_AVX2_lookup` but with a much less efficient way to accumulate the results across iterations.

Comment: I was totally missing the point that instructions without dependency can run in parallel. I mean the code doesn't make sense when each instruction is run sequentially.

Comment: Starting with Ice Lake Xeon, there is an AVX51 SIMD pop count instruction, supporting 128-bit, 256-bit, and 512-bit vectors.  For 64-bit values, 512 bits gives 8 pops per instruction with a throughput of one instruction per cycle and a latency of three cycles -- so 2x faster than Zen3 at 4/clock.  The AVX512 advantage increases rapidly if the pop count is being performed on smaller integers -- up to 64 per cycle for 8 bit values in 512-bit registers.

Comment: @JohnDMcCalpin: Yes, even gcc as well as clang auto-vectorize with that with `-march=icelake-client`.  https://godbolt.org/z/rso96MWEo (Or `icelake-server`. On the client side unfortunately not quite "starting with" since AVX-512 disappointingly disappeared again with Alder Lake, and Intel's firmware updates lock off the ability to enable it when the E-cores are disabled.  Maybe so they can sell cores with defects in the high-256 of execution units?  But if so, you'd think they'd have already fused them off...  Anyway, that rant's not really relevant here.)

Comment: Oh, interesting, I hadn't realized AVX512 BITALG for `vpopcntb/w` was introduced in Ice Lake as well.  So Knight's Mill is the only CPU with `vpopcntd`/`q` (VPOPCNT feature) for 32/64 bit chunks but not `vpopcntb`/`w`.

Comment: @JohnDMcCalpin: ICX and ICL should both support both.  GCC and clang `-march=icelake-server` both accept `_mm_popcnt_epi16` and compile it to `vpopcntw`. https://godbolt.org/z/5GxfaeEEr  Are you saying they're both buggy, and that instruction will fault on real Ice Lake?
  Wikipedia agrees with gcc/clang that only Knight's Mill had VPOPCNT without BITALG https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512#CPUs_with_AVX-512, but of course it's possible they could all be working from the same wrong information.  If you checked CPUID in a VM, did it maybe filter that feature bit?

Comment: @JohnDMcCalpin: http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/GenuineIntel/GenuineIntel00606A6_ICX_InstLatX64.txt from an IceLake-SP confirms that server Ice Lake does indeed have the AVX512_BITALG CPUID feature, and 1/clock 3c latency VPOPCNTB/W/D/Q for x/y/zmm vector widths is there in the test results.  (Agreed with there being too many separate extension names / feature bits to keep track of, though.  I wouldn't have remembered it was BITALG for those byte/word popcounts, plus one other instruction, if I hadn't looked it up.)