# AVX2 column population count algorithm over each bit-column separately

Tags: c++, visual-c++, x86, simd, avx2

For a project I'm working on I need to count the number of set bits per column in ripped `PDF` image data.

I'm trying to get the total set bit count for each column in the entire `PDF` job (all pages).

The data, once ripped, is stored in a `MemoryMappedFile` with no backing file (in memory).

The PDF page dimensions are 13952 pixels x 15125 pixels. The total size of the resulting ripped data can be calculated by multiplying the length (height) of the `PDF` in pixels by the width in bytes. The ripped data is `1 bit == 1 pixel`. So the size of a ripped page in bytes is `(13952 / 8) * 15125`.

Note that the width is always a multiple of `64 bits`.

I'll have to count the set bits for each column in each page of a `PDF` (which could be tens of thousands of pages) after being ripped.

I first approached the problem with a basic solution of just looping through each byte and counting the number of set bits and placing the results in a `vector`. I've since whittled down the algorithm to whats shown below. I've gone from a execution time of ~350ms to ~120ms.

```
static void count_dots( )
{
    using namespace diag;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    std::vector<std::size_t> dot_counts( 13952, 0 );
    uint64_t* ptr_dot_counts{ dot_counts.data( ) };

    std::vector<uint64_t> ripped_pdf_data( 3297250, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFUL );
    const uint64_t* ptr_data{ ripped_pdf_data.data( ) };

    std::size_t line_count{ 0 };
    std::size_t counter{ ripped_pdf_data.size( ) };

    stopwatch sw;
    sw.start( );

    while( counter > 0 )
    {
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 7 ) & 0x0100000000000000UL ) >> 56;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 7 ) & 0x0001000000000000UL ) >> 48;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 7 ) & 0x0000010000000000UL ) >> 40;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 7 ) & 0x0000000100000000UL ) >> 32;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 7 ) & 0x0000000001000000UL ) >> 24;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 7 ) & 0x0000000000010000UL ) >> 16;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 7 ) & 0x0000000000000100UL ) >> 8;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 7 ) & 0x0000000000000001UL ) >> 0;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 6 ) & 0x0100000000000000UL ) >> 56;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 6 ) & 0x0001000000000000UL ) >> 48;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 6 ) & 0x0000010000000000UL ) >> 40;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 6 ) & 0x0000000100000000UL ) >> 32;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 6 ) & 0x0000000001000000UL ) >> 24;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 6 ) & 0x0000000000010000UL ) >> 16;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 6 ) & 0x0000000000000100UL ) >> 8;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 6 ) & 0x0000000000000001UL ) >> 0;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 5 ) & 0x0100000000000000UL ) >> 56;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 5 ) & 0x0001000000000000UL ) >> 48;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 5 ) & 0x0000010000000000UL ) >> 40;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 5 ) & 0x0000000100000000UL ) >> 32;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 5 ) & 0x0000000001000000UL ) >> 24;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 5 ) & 0x0000000000010000UL ) >> 16;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 5 ) & 0x0000000000000100UL ) >> 8;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 5 ) & 0x0000000000000001UL ) >> 0;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 4 ) & 0x0100000000000000UL ) >> 56;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 4 ) & 0x0001000000000000UL ) >> 48;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 4 ) & 0x0000010000000000UL ) >> 40;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 4 ) & 0x0000000100000000UL ) >> 32;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 4 ) & 0x0000000001000000UL ) >> 24;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 4 ) & 0x0000000000010000UL ) >> 16;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 4 ) & 0x0000000000000100UL ) >> 8;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 4 ) & 0x0000000000000001UL ) >> 0;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 3 ) & 0x0100000000000000UL ) >> 56;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 3 ) & 0x0001000000000000UL ) >> 48;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 3 ) & 0x0000010000000000UL ) >> 40;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 3 ) & 0x0000000100000000UL ) >> 32;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 3 ) & 0x0000000001000000UL ) >> 24;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 3 ) & 0x0000000000010000UL ) >> 16;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 3 ) & 0x0000000000000100UL ) >> 8;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 3 ) & 0x0000000000000001UL ) >> 0;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 2 ) & 0x0100000000000000UL ) >> 56;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 2 ) & 0x0001000000000000UL ) >> 48;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 2 ) & 0x0000010000000000UL ) >> 40;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 2 ) & 0x0000000100000000UL ) >> 32;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 2 ) & 0x0000000001000000UL ) >> 24;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 2 ) & 0x0000000000010000UL ) >> 16;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 2 ) & 0x0000000000000100UL ) >> 8;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 2 ) & 0x0000000000000001UL ) >> 0;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 1 ) & 0x0100000000000000UL ) >> 56;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 1 ) & 0x0001000000000000UL ) >> 48;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 1 ) & 0x0000010000000000UL ) >> 40;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 1 ) & 0x0000000100000000UL ) >> 32;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 1 ) & 0x0000000001000000UL ) >> 24;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 1 ) & 0x0000000000010000UL ) >> 16;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 1 ) & 0x0000000000000100UL ) >> 8;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 1 ) & 0x0000000000000001UL ) >> 0;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 0 ) & 0x0100000000000000UL ) >> 56;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 0 ) & 0x0001000000000000UL ) >> 48;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 0 ) & 0x0000010000000000UL ) >> 40;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 0 ) & 0x0000000100000000UL ) >> 32;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 0 ) & 0x0000000001000000UL ) >> 24;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 0 ) & 0x0000000000010000UL ) >> 16;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 0 ) & 0x0000000000000100UL ) >> 8;
        *ptr_dot_counts++ += ( ( *ptr_data >> 0 ) & 0x0000000000000001UL ) >> 0;

        ++ptr_data;
        --counter;
        if( ++line_count >= 218 )
        {
            ptr_dot_counts = dot_counts.data( );
            line_count = 0;
        }
    }   

    sw.stop( );
    std::cout << sw.elapsed<milliseconds>( ) << "ms\n";
}
```

Unfortunately this is still going to add a lot of extra processing time which isn't going to be acceptable.

The above code is ugly and wont win any beauty contests but it has helped in reducing execution time.
Since the original version I wrote I've done the following:

- Use `pointers` instead of `indexers`
- Process the data in chunks of `uint64` instead of `uint8`
- Manually unroll the `for` loop for traversing each `bit` in each `byte` of a `uint64`
- Use a final `bit shift` instead of `__popcnt64` for counting the set `bit` after masking

For this test I'm generating phony ripped data where each `bit` is set to `1`. The `dot_counts` `vector` should contain `15125` for each `element` after the test has completed.

I'm hoping some folks here can help me in getting the algorithms average execution time below 100ms.
I do not care what-so-ever about portability here.

- The target machine's CPU: `Xeon E5-2680 v4 - Intel`
- Compiler: `MSVC++ 14.23`
- OS: `Windows 10`
- C++ Version: `C++17`
- Compiler flags: `/O2` `/arch:AVX2`

A very similar question was asked ~8 years ago:
[How to quickly count bits into separate bins in a series of ints on Sandy Bridge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793997/how-to-quickly-count-bits-into-separate-bins-in-a-series-of-ints-on-sandy-bridge)

(Editor's note: perhaps you missed [Count each bit-position separately over many 64-bit bitmasks, with AVX but not AVX2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55081525/count-each-bit-position-separately-over-many-64-bit-bitmasks-with-avx-but-not-a) which has some more recent faster answers, at least for going down a column instead of along a row in contiguous memory.  Maybe you can go 1 or 2 cache-lines wide down a column so you can keep your counters hot in SIMD registers.)

When I compare what I have thus far to the accepted answer I'm fairly close. I was already processing in chunks of `uint64` instead of `uint8`. I'm just wondering if there is more I can do, whether that be with intrinsics, assembly, or something simple like changing what data structures I'm using.

Comment: I might take a deeper look a little later, but from a quick skim you should be able to increase speed enough by simply caching bitwise results. You're repeating right shift 8x for each byte which is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @PickleRick When you say "caching bitwise results" do you mean caching the result of say `*ptr_data >> 7` and reusing it?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Save the shifted ptr_data results for all 8 bytes so they don't have to be recalculated (8 * 8 = 64) times each iteration.

Comment: Just for clarification: Your images are stored row-major? Is the size always the same, or can you only guarantee that the width is a multiple of 64? Do you need the result as a vector of `uint64` or would a vector of `uint16` be fine as well? And can you make any assumptions about alignment?

Comment: @PickleRick good idea, ill test it out

Comment: Let me know how it goes, if it's still not fast enough then I'll take another look a little later today if you still haven't gotten an acceptable answer.

Comment: @chtz the data is stored in a `contiguous` memory block (`1D ` array), so `row-major`. The length (height) is dynamic but will always be a multiple of `5`. Currently I use `uint64` to store the counts because I'm collecting the total dot count for the entire job (all PDF pages). That behaviour can be changed though. I could just store the total for each page and than combine the resulting `vectors` at the end

Comment: This: "count the set bits for each column in **each** page" made me assume you are primarily interested in the per-page counts. But you are (only?) interested in the total count (for each column)?

Comment: @chtz correct, I'll edit the question to clarify that.

Comment: I should add that right shift 0 won't actually do anything so those 8 can be removed. Although the compiler optimization should pick that up so it may not even make a difference. I'm on mobile still but, like I said before, let me know if that quick change isn't enough and I'll get back to you a little later when I get to a computer.

Comment: @PickleRick OK so I stored the `bit shift` results but no change. I suspect the compiler saw what I was doing and `cached` the result in to a variable for me. I'll paste the code into Compiler Explorer and see what the compiler is doing.

Comment: The assembly would be useful, thanks. Between compiler optimization and bitwise operators being so low latency it's not too surprising but I was hoping that would be enough. I'll be at a computer within the next hour and will take a deeper look for you.

Comment: `( ( *ptr_data >> 7 ) & 0x0100000000000000UL ) >> 56` can be `!!(*ptr_data & 0x80'00'00'00'00'00'00'00UL)` and `( ( *ptr_data >> 7 ) & 0x0001000000000000UL ) >> 48` be `!!(*ptr_data & 0x40'00'00'00'00'00'00'00UL)` and so on.

Comment: And to avoid possible aliasing, you might store `*ptr_data` in local variable.

Comment: @Jarod42 Interesting. I did try to `implicitly` convert to `bool` before but I was still `bit-shifting`. Ill give your suggestions a try now.

Comment: `!!` seems not good as msvc creates a jump, but my point is to do only one shift:`(*ptr_data & 0x80'00'00'00'00'00'00'00UL) >> 63` or even `(*ptr_data >> 63) & 0x01`

Comment: Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51475704/matrix-transpose-and-population-count)  with some benchmarks, following an idea of Peter Cordes.

It works with 32-bit masks but should be improved for 64-bit masks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be done with AVX2, as tagged.

In order to make this work out properly, I recommend `vector<uint16_t>` for the counts. Adding into the counts is the biggest problem, and the more we need to widen, the bigger the problem. `uint16_t` is enough to count one page, so you can count one page at the time and add the counters into a set of wider counters for the totals. That is some overhead, but much less than having to widen more in the main loop.

The big-endian ordering of the counts is very annoying, introducing even more shuffles to get it right. So I recommend getting it *wrong* and reordering the counts later (maybe during summing them into the totals?). The order of "right shift by 7 first, then 6, then 5" can be maintained for free, because we get to choose the shift counts for the 64bit blocks any way we want. So in the code below, the actual order of counts is:

- Bit 7 of the least significant byte,
- Bit 7 of the second byte
- ...
- Bit 7 of the most significant byte,
- Bit 6 of the least significant byte,
- ...

So every group of 8 is reversed. (at least this is what I intended to do, AVX2 [unpacks](https://www.officedaytime.com/simd512e/simdimg/unpack.php?f=punpcklbw) are confusing)

Code (not tested):

```
while( counter > 0 )
{
    __m256i data = _mm256_set1_epi64x(*ptr_data);        
    __m256i data1 = _mm256_srlv_epi64(data, _mm256_set_epi64x(4, 6, 5, 7));
    __m256i data2 = _mm256_srlv_epi64(data, _mm256_set_epi64x(0, 2, 1, 3));
    data1 = _mm256_and_si256(data1, _mm256_set1_epi8(1));
    data2 = _mm256_and_si256(data2, _mm256_set1_epi8(1));

    __m256i zero = _mm256_setzero_si256();

    __m256i c = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)&ptr_dot_counts[0]);
    c = _mm256_add_epi16(_mm256_unpacklo_epi8(data1, zero), c);
    _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)&ptr_dot_counts[0], c);

    c = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)&ptr_dot_counts[16]);
    c = _mm256_add_epi16(_mm256_unpackhi_epi8(data1, zero), c);
    _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)&ptr_dot_counts[16], c);

    c = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)&ptr_dot_counts[32]);
    c = _mm256_add_epi16(_mm256_unpacklo_epi8(data2, zero), c);
    _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)&ptr_dot_counts[32], c);

    c = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)&ptr_dot_counts[48]);
    c = _mm256_add_epi16(_mm256_unpackhi_epi8(data2, zero), c);
    _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)&ptr_dot_counts[48], c);

    ptr_dot_counts += 64;
    ++ptr_data;
    --counter;
    if( ++line_count >= 218 )
    {
        ptr_dot_counts = dot_counts.data( );
        line_count = 0;
    }
}
```

This can be further unrolled, handling multiple rows at once. That is good because, as mentioned earlier, summing into the counters is the biggest problem, and unrolling by rows would do less of that and more plain summing in registers.

Somme intrinsics used:

- `_mm256_set1_epi64x`, copies one `int64_t` to all 4 of the 64bit elements of the vector. Also fine for `uint64_t`.
- `_mm256_set_epi64x`, turns 4 64bit values into a vector.
- [`_mm256_srlv_epi64`](https://www.officedaytime.com/simd512e/simdimg/binop.php?f=vpsrlvq), shift right logical, with variable count (can be a different count for each element).
- `_mm256_and_si256`, just bitwise AND.
- [`_mm256_add_epi16`](https://www.officedaytime.com/simd512e/simdimg/binop.php?f=paddw), addition, works on 16bit elements.
- [`_mm256_unpacklo_epi8`](https://www.officedaytime.com/simd512e/simdimg/unpack.php?f=punpcklbw) and [`_mm256_unpackhi_epi8`](https://www.officedaytime.com/simd512e/simdimg/unpack.php?f=punpckhbw), probably best explained by the diagrams on that page

---

It's possible to sum "vertically", using one `uint64_t` to hold all the 0th bits of the 64 individual sums, an other `uint64_t` to hold all the 1st bits of the sums etc. The addition can be done by emulating full adders (the circuit component) with bitwise arithmetic. Then instead of adding just 0 or 1 to the counters, bigger numbers are added all at once.

The vertical sums can also be vectorized, but that would significantly inflate the code that adds the vertical sums to the column sums, so I didn't do that here. It should help, but it's just a lot of code.

Example (not tested):

```
size_t y;
// sum 7 rows at once
for (y = 0; (y + 6) < 15125; y += 7) {
    ptr_dot_counts = dot_counts.data( );
    ptr_data = ripped_pdf_data.data( ) + y * 218;
    for (size_t x = 0; x < 218; x++) {
        uint64_t dataA = ptr_data[0];
        uint64_t dataB = ptr_data[218];
        uint64_t dataC = ptr_data[218 * 2];
        uint64_t dataD = ptr_data[218 * 3];
        uint64_t dataE = ptr_data[218 * 4];
        uint64_t dataF = ptr_data[218 * 5];
        uint64_t dataG = ptr_data[218 * 6];
        // vertical sums, 7 bits to 3
        uint64_t abc0 = (dataA ^ dataB) ^ dataC;
        uint64_t abc1 = (dataA ^ dataB) & dataC | (dataA & dataB);
        uint64_t def0 = (dataD ^ dataE) ^ dataF;
        uint64_t def1 = (dataD ^ dataE) & dataF | (dataD & dataE);
        uint64_t bit0 = (abc0 ^ def0) ^ dataG;
        uint64_t c1   = (abc0 ^ def0) & dataG | (abc0 & def0);
        uint64_t bit1 = (abc1 ^ def1) ^ c1;
        uint64_t bit2 = (abc1 ^ def1) & c1 | (abc1 & def1);
        // add vertical sums to column counts
        __m256i bit0v = _mm256_set1_epi64x(bit0);
        __m256i data01 = _mm256_srlv_epi64(bit0v, _mm256_set_epi64x(4, 6, 5, 7));
        __m256i data02 = _mm256_srlv_epi64(bit0v, _mm256_set_epi64x(0, 2, 1, 3));
        data01 = _mm256_and_si256(data01, _mm256_set1_epi8(1));
        data02 = _mm256_and_si256(data02, _mm256_set1_epi8(1));
        __m256i bit1v = _mm256_set1_epi64x(bit1);
        __m256i data11 = _mm256_srlv_epi64(bit1v, _mm256_set_epi64x(4, 6, 5, 7));
        __m256i data12 = _mm256_srlv_epi64(bit1v, _mm256_set_epi64x(0, 2, 1, 3));
        data11 = _mm256_and_si256(data11, _mm256_set1_epi8(1));
        data12 = _mm256_and_si256(data12, _mm256_set1_epi8(1));
        data11 = _mm256_add_epi8(data11, data11);
        data12 = _mm256_add_epi8(data12, data12);
        __m256i bit2v = _mm256_set1_epi64x(bit2);
        __m256i data21 = _mm256_srlv_epi64(bit2v, _mm256_set_epi64x(4, 6, 5, 7));
        __m256i data22 = _mm256_srlv_epi64(bit2v, _mm256_set_epi64x(0, 2, 1, 3));
        data21 = _mm256_and_si256(data21, _mm256_set1_epi8(1));
        data22 = _mm256_and_si256(data22, _mm256_set1_epi8(1));
        data21 = _mm256_slli_epi16(data21, 2);
        data22 = _mm256_slli_epi16(data22, 2);
        __m256i data1 = _mm256_add_epi8(_mm256_add_epi8(data01, data11), data21);
        __m256i data2 = _mm256_add_epi8(_mm256_add_epi8(data02, data12), data22);

        __m256i zero = _mm256_setzero_si256();

        __m256i c = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)&ptr_dot_counts[0]);
        c = _mm256_add_epi16(_mm256_unpacklo_epi8(data1, zero), c);
        _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)&ptr_dot_counts[0], c);

        c = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)&ptr_dot_counts[16]);
        c = _mm256_add_epi16(_mm256_unpackhi_epi8(data1, zero), c);
        _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)&ptr_dot_counts[16], c);

        c = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)&ptr_dot_counts[32]);
        c = _mm256_add_epi16(_mm256_unpacklo_epi8(data2, zero), c);
        _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)&ptr_dot_counts[32], c);

        c = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)&ptr_dot_counts[48]);
        c = _mm256_add_epi16(_mm256_unpackhi_epi8(data2, zero), c);
        _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)&ptr_dot_counts[48], c);


        ptr_dot_counts += 64;
        ++ptr_data;
    }
}
// leftover rows
for (; y < 15125; y++) {
    ptr_dot_counts = dot_counts.data( );
    ptr_data = ripped_pdf_data.data( ) + y * 218;
    for (size_t x = 0; x < 218; x++) {
        __m256i data = _mm256_set1_epi64x(*ptr_data);
        __m256i data1 = _mm256_srlv_epi64(data, _mm256_set_epi64x(4, 6, 5, 7));
        __m256i data2 = _mm256_srlv_epi64(data, _mm256_set_epi64x(0, 2, 1, 3));
        data1 = _mm256_and_si256(data1, _mm256_set1_epi8(1));
        data2 = _mm256_and_si256(data2, _mm256_set1_epi8(1));

        __m256i zero = _mm256_setzero_si256();

        __m256i c = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)&ptr_dot_counts[0]);
        c = _mm256_add_epi16(_mm256_unpacklo_epi8(data1, zero), c);
        _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)&ptr_dot_counts[0], c);

        c = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)&ptr_dot_counts[16]);
        c = _mm256_add_epi16(_mm256_unpackhi_epi8(data1, zero), c);
        _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)&ptr_dot_counts[16], c);

        c = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)&ptr_dot_counts[32]);
        c = _mm256_add_epi16(_mm256_unpacklo_epi8(data2, zero), c);
        _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)&ptr_dot_counts[32], c);

        c = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)&ptr_dot_counts[48]);
        c = _mm256_add_epi16(_mm256_unpackhi_epi8(data2, zero), c);
        _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)&ptr_dot_counts[48], c);


        ptr_dot_counts += 64;
        ++ptr_data;
    }
}
```

---

The second best so far was a simpler approach, more like the first version except doing runs of `yloopLen` rows at once to take advantage of fast 8bit sums:

```
size_t yloopLen = 32;
size_t yblock = yloopLen * 1;
size_t yy;
for (yy = 0; yy < 15125; yy += yblock) {
    for (size_t x = 0; x < 218; x++) {
        ptr_data = ripped_pdf_data.data() + x;
        ptr_dot_counts = dot_counts.data() + x * 64;
        __m256i zero = _mm256_setzero_si256();

        __m256i c1 = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)&ptr_dot_counts[0]);
        __m256i c2 = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)&ptr_dot_counts[16]);
        __m256i c3 = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)&ptr_dot_counts[32]);
        __m256i c4 = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)&ptr_dot_counts[48]);

        size_t end = std::min(yy + yblock, size_t(15125));
        size_t y;
        for (y = yy; y < end; y += yloopLen) {
            size_t len = std::min(size_t(yloopLen), end - y);
            __m256i count1 = zero;
            __m256i count2 = zero;

            for (size_t t = 0; t < len; t++) {
                __m256i data = _mm256_set1_epi64x(ptr_data[(y + t) * 218]);
                __m256i data1 = _mm256_srlv_epi64(data, _mm256_set_epi64x(4, 6, 5, 7));
                __m256i data2 = _mm256_srlv_epi64(data, _mm256_set_epi64x(0, 2, 1, 3));
                data1 = _mm256_and_si256(data1, _mm256_set1_epi8(1));
                data2 = _mm256_and_si256(data2, _mm256_set1_epi8(1));
                count1 = _mm256_add_epi8(count1, data1);
                count2 = _mm256_add_epi8(count2, data2);
            }

            c1 = _mm256_add_epi16(_mm256_unpacklo_epi8(count1, zero), c1);
            c2 = _mm256_add_epi16(_mm256_unpackhi_epi8(count1, zero), c2);
            c3 = _mm256_add_epi16(_mm256_unpacklo_epi8(count2, zero), c3);
            c4 = _mm256_add_epi16(_mm256_unpackhi_epi8(count2, zero), c4);
        }

        _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)&ptr_dot_counts[0], c1);
        _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)&ptr_dot_counts[16], c2);
        _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)&ptr_dot_counts[32], c3);
        _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)&ptr_dot_counts[48], c4);
    }
}
```

There were some measurement issues before, in the end this wasn't actually better, but also not much worse than the fancier "vertical sum" version above.

Comment: I would also consider doing the inner-most additions on a byte-level (or even hierarchically 2-bits, 4-bits, 8-bits, 16-bits). And I think one of the main things to consider is how to use the registers and the cache optimally.

Comment: I'm attempting to mentally unpack the above code. Currently when I run the code as-is the `vector<uint16_t> dot_counts( 13952, 0 )` is showing incorrect counts. The first `64` elements show a count of '20450', while the remaining elements show '0'. I'm unsure if this is a bug (as you said untested code) or equally possible is that I'm not understanding how the `counts` are supposed to be updated. I'm just walking through the code snippet now to try and understand it.

Comment: I forgot to advance the pointer, but maybe more is wrong. If/when it stops being wrong, maybe I'll add some of @chtz's suggestions (or he can just write an answer)

Comment: @harold wow that's impressive. The execution time went from an average of ~110ms down to ~10ms. The `dot_counts` counts are correct after advancing the pointer. Now I need to do my job and understand what the code is doing line by line before I implement it. Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: @WBuck I've added an other (weirder) version. If you want I can add some references for how the instructions that I used work.

Comment: @harold Yeah I'd love the references. Ill also have to give this newer version a try as well.

Comment: Version 2 brought the execution time from ~10ms (version 1) down to ~5ms. You've given me a lot of homework to do.

Comment: @WBuck and harold: my answer on [Count each bit-position separately over many 64-bit bitmasks, with AVX but not AVX2](//stackoverflow.com/a/55083822) has a gradual-widening version of this using scalar `uint64_t`.  I didn't take the time to manually vectorize it; you'd want to go down columns maybe 2 `__m256i` vectors at once to do whole cache lines.  Register pressure might be a problem if you wanted to go wider without AVX512.  Cache-blocking could help avoid wasted cache traffic (especially L2 spatial prefetches that you never load before a conflict miss).

Comment: @WBuck and harold: Oh, see also https://github.com/mklarqvist/positional-popcount.  It has an SSE blend version, and AVX512 harley-seal, with significant speedups listed.  (But it's positional within k-bit words, not across whole rows of many words, unless it works for very large `k`).  Harley-Seal is I think this is what Harold is doing implementing full-adders with different place-value bits in different registers.  It reduces 3 inputs to 2 and can be applied repeatedly.  So yes, doing that going down columns should work well.

Comment: https://github.com/WojciechMula/sse-popcount/blob/master/popcnt-avx2-harley-seal.cpp has a horizontal/flat popcnt over a big array that produces a single scalar result, but it's an example of Harley-Seal with just AVX2, not AVX512 for `vpternlogd`.

Comment: @harold So I've been stepping through the code for the final example and I'm a bit confused about the inner most `for` loops. It appears as if we continuously loop over the same `255` `uint64` values `255` times. What I expected was that it would loop over the the initial `uint64` value for each of the `255` rows and than bump `x` to the next `uint64`in the first row. The inner `for` loops would than offset from the newly offset `ptr_data` position. Also note that I've probably misinterpreted the code and just need more time stepping through it.

Comment: Correction, I meant to say It appears as if we continuously loop over the same 255 uint64 values 10 times.

Comment: @WBuck yea I've fixed it now, forgot the `y`. Btw it's odd how that doesn't change the performance much. Also the all-ones nature of the data is not so great for debugging lol, the result is almost always the same even if the code is wrong

Comment: @harold yeah, I had to change the test data to see the bug. The all 1’s wasn’t helping haha