# Is there an AVX2 instruction (and intrinsic) to broadcast load a 16 bit value 16 times into an __m256i?

Tags: c++, sse, intrinsics, avx, avx2

In the following code, I can use avx2 to count the number of 1 bits in each position
separately 16 bits at a time, but there are 4 missing instructions on the lines labelled loadLow16. I need an instruction that loads a 16 bit value and puts it in each 16 bits of the avx2 register (16 times). Is there an instruction to do this, or is there a better way to do this?

```
void countHistBits4(const uint64_t p[], uint32_t n, uint32_t hist[64]) {
  uint16_t masks[16] = {1, 1<<1, 1<<2, 1<<3, 1<<4, 1<<5, 1<<6, 1<<7,
            1<<8, 1<<9, 1<<10, 1<<11, 1<<12, 1<<13, 1<<14, 1<<16};
    __m256i mask = _mm256_load_si256((__m256*)masks);
    __m256i count1 = _mm256_setzero_si256();
    __m256i count2 = _mm256_setzero_si256();
    __m256i count3 = _mm256_setzero_si256();
    __m256i count4 = _mm256_setzero_si256();
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      __m256i v1 = loadLow16(p[i] & 0xFFFF);
      __m256i v2 = loadLow16((p[i] >> 16) & 0xFFFF);
      __m256i v3 = loadLow16((p[i] >> 32) & 0xFFFF);
      __m256i v4 = loadLow16((p[i] >> 48) & 0xFFFF);
      v1 = _mm256_and_si256(v1, mask);
      count1 = _mm256_adds_epi16 (count1, vals);
      v2 = _mm256_and_si256(v2, mask);
      count2 = _mm256_adds_epi16 (count2, vals);
      v3 = _mm256_and_si256(v3, mask);
      count3 = _mm256_adds_epi16 (count3, vals);
      v4 = _mm256_and_si256(v4, mask);
      count4 = _mm256_adds_epi16 (count4, vals);
    }
}
```

Comment: _mm256_set1_epi16

Comment: `vpbroadcastw` works with a memory or xmm source.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpbroadcastb:vpbroadcastw:vpbroadcastd:vpbroadcastq

Comment: Also, see https://github.com/mklarqvist/positional-popcount for efficient SIMD positional-popcount, especially over arrays with multiple vectors of data, for chunk sizes including 16-bit.  It's possible to do somewhat better than this by maintaining higher information density (not masking down to only 0 / 1 at the bottom of a 16-bit element), meaning you get more work out of each element.

Comment: Also, you'd need a variable-count shift before the `adds` for this to really work; for example the `1<<15` mask (which you typoed as `1<<16` which overflows a uint16_t), will produce a `0` or `1<<15`.  Adding two of those will signed-saturate to `0x8000` (-INT16_MIN), i.e. the masked original value, so you can't usefully add at all for that top element, without a shift!

Comment: Possible duplicates for the position popcount part: [AVX2 column population count algorithm over each bit-column separately](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58486138) / [Count each bit-position separately over many 64-bit bitmasks, with AVX but not AVX2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55081525) .  But I haven't looked to see if using techniques that work for 64 separate counts are appropriate / optimal for 16 separate counts- certainly you could just add 4 counts down to 1 to get 16-bit positional from 64-bit.  But probably best to look at that github link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your overall positional-popcount problem, see https://github.com/mklarqvist/positional-popcount for heavily optimized implementations, which are also correct unlike this, which you obviously haven't had time to debug yet since you were missing a building block. Adding multiple `x & (1<<15)` results in an `int16_t` element is going to saturate right away, so you'd need something, perhaps a variable-count shift or a compare like `x & mask == mask`. Or probably better a total redesign:  Related SO Q&As:

- [AVX2 column population count algorithm over each bit-column separately](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58486138)
- [Count each bit-position separately over many 64-bit bitmasks, with AVX but not AVX2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55081525)
- https://github.com/mklarqvist/positional-popcount - at least as good as anything in the SO Q&As, I think.

---

### The title question: broadcast a `uint16_t`

The instruction is [`vpbroadcastw`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpbroadcastb:vpbroadcastw:vpbroadcastd:vpbroadcastq). It works with a memory or xmm source.  On Intel CPUs, it decodes to a load and a shuffle (port 5) uop, unlike 32, 64, or 128-bit broadcasts which are handled purely in the load port.

The intrinsics for it are:

- `__m256i _mm256_set1_epi16( int16_t )` - if you only have a scalar.
- `__m256i _mm256_broadcastw_epi16 (__m128i a)` - to broadcast the bottom element of a vector.

To avoid violating the strict-aliasing rule in C, you're correct that accessing `uint64_t p[]` elements and masking them is a safe approach, while point a `uint16_t *` at it wouldn't be.  (If you deref it normally; but unfortunately there's no load intrinsic that hides the deref inside an aliasing-safe intrinsic, so you'd have to memcpy into a `uint16_t` tmp var or something...)

Modern GCC is smart enough to compile `__m256i v4 = _mm256_set1_epi16((p[i] >> 48) & 0xFFFF);` into `vpbroadcastw    ymm0, WORD PTR [rdi+6+rdx*8]`, not doing anything stupid like an actual 64-bit scalar shift and then `vmovd` + xmm-source broadcast.  (even with only `-Og` https://godbolt.org/z/W6o5hKTbz)

But that's when only using one of the counts, with the others optimized away.   (I just used a `volatile __m256i sink` to assign things to as a way to stop the optimizer removing the loop entirely.)

https://godbolt.org/z/fzs9PEbMq shows with heavier optimization, using count2 and count4 gets GCC to do a scalar load of the uint64_t and break it up with two separate scalar shifts, before  `vmovd xmm0, edx` / ... / `vmovd xmm0, eax`.  So that's quite bad. :/

```
     // compiles to a vpbroadcastw load with an offset
     // but violates strict aliasing
      __m256i v2 = _mm256_set1_epi16( *(1 + (uint16_t*)&p[i])  );
```

To make that safe, you could use `memcpy` into a temporary, or GNU C `__attribute__((may_alias))`.  (The same attribute is used in the definition of `__m256i` itself).

```
typedef uint16_t aliasing_u16 __attribute__((aligned(1), may_alias));

      __m256i v1 = _mm256_set1_epi16(*(0 + (aliasing_u16*)&p[i]));
      __m256i v2 = _mm256_set1_epi16(*(1 + (aliasing_u16*)&p[i]));
      __m256i v3 = _mm256_set1_epi16(*(2 + (aliasing_u16*)&p[i]));
      __m256i v4 = _mm256_set1_epi16(*(3 + (aliasing_u16*)&p[i]));
```

Compiles with 4x vpbroadcastw loads (https://godbolt.org/z/6v9esqK9P). (Instructions using those loads elided)

```
        vpbroadcastw    ymm1, WORD PTR [rdi]
...
        add     rdi, 8
        vpbroadcastw    ymm1, WORD PTR [rdi-6]
...
        vpbroadcastw    ymm1, WORD PTR [rdi-4]
...
        vpbroadcastw    ymm1, WORD PTR [rdi-2]
...
```

This is probably better to avoid bottlenecks on port 5 on Intel CPUs.  Both `vmovd xmm, eax` and `vpbroadcastw ymm,xmm` are 1 uop that can only run on port 5 on Skylake-family CPUs.  (https://agner.org/optimize/  https://uops.info/).

`vpbroadcastw` with a memory source still needs a shuffle uop (p5), but getting the data from elsewhere into the SIMD domain uses a load port instead of another port 5 uop.  And it can micro-fuse the load into a single front-end uop.